# Rules in Shared Inbox - Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

We are only allowed one outlook profile in our organisation. Which means I automatically login to my personal profile when I open Outlook 2013. The Share Inbox is then open via my personal profile. The issue is that I cannot set rules which affect the Shared Inbox if I'm signed in as me.

Is there a workaround which I can do to set rules for the shared inbox?
ie. Transfer mail from Shared Inbox to Shared SubFolder.

I also tried the Web Application, and it's the same, it only allows me to set rules for my personal inbox.

I'm theoretically the admin for the Shared Inbox, but they do not allow you to login as "Shared Inbox". These are my limitations. Have anyone got any suggestions as a work around?

Comment: Yes you can use vba, what is your trying to do? just move items from inbox to subfolder?

Comment: I already mentioned in my post that I am not allowed to add an account. The first sentence say we are only allowed one profile/account and that is my limitation and I am looking for an alternative. The Groovypost you are suggesting is the only way we can see the inbox, which gives me my problem - unable to set up a rule for the Shared Inbox.

Comment: " .. they do not allow you to login as "Shared Inbox".  If you are able to use the "Add Account", you log in as yourself. The other account appears without having to sign in separately. When you go to rules you should see a dropdown list with the two inboxes. (You need to prefix your comment with @nit if you respond directly to me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this questions. The limitation does not allow me to set rules on the shared inbox. VBA is the only possible alternative. Outlook VBA is also disabled, so I'm doing this via Excel VBA.

And NO, I cannot add another account. I can add ADDITIONAL inbox to be opened in MY account. But I cannot add another account. Thanks that's just the policy applied to our organisation.